# How to get the item of a v-data-table row?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table (-virtual, which shouldn't matter) and I want to call a method with the item (user in users array) at the row I clicked.

```html
<v-data-table-virtual
  v-model="selectedToDelete"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="users"
  :key="users"
  @click:row="editUser()"
/>
```

Is there any way to do it (best without using the item slot)?

---

(I am using Vuetify 3.3.15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click:row` event gives `Event, { item: DataTableItem }` for the handlers. So you an implement your handler like the following to get the item and perform specific action with any of the item properties.

```js
handleRowClick(e, { item }) {
  console.log(item)
  // call any method here
},
```

See [demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Additionally, I needed to remove the "()" from the `@click:row` parameter value.